# Softwares/Pre-requisites to use Appium

Tags: java, appium

There is lot of information scattered over web but I am not able to finalize the softwares/pre-requisites to start automation with Appium.

We are planning to introduce Appium for app testing. The coding language would  be Java. It would be great if I get an expert advice on all the required softwares.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Did you read the Appium documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through it and through other sources. Some of them confuse each other. Would be great if I get concrete answer with justification for using a particular software as a pre-requisite.

Comment: You should edit your question to show the sources which you find confusing. Provide exact quotes and links to the sources.

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice, I don't want this question to be too much complicated. It is a straight forward question. I am new to Appium. If i were an expert I would not have asked such basic question. I hope you understand. So if you know the answer then please respond.

Comment: Because ... if we con't know what you are finding confusing, we will most likely just add to it!

Comment: The straight-forward answer to the straight-forward question is: "read the documentation and then tell us what you find confusing!"  Start here: http://appium.io/getting-started.html  StackOverflow is not intended to be a source of rewritten documentation.  It is a Q&A site.  For that we need concrete Questions.

Comment: @ Stephan C, sometimes it is written like 'Node.JS' is not required and in some other sources it is written as required.

Comment: Well what does the official documentation say about that?  What it says is *"You can run an Appium server using node.js or using the application, see below."*.  So there's your answer!  (It may be that other sources **assume** that you are using node.js ... but that doesn't mean that node.js is required to use Appium)

Comment: Can I assume following softwares as final list:- ANDROID SDK, JDK (Java Development Kit),TestNG, Eclipse, Selenium Server JAR, Webdriver Language Binding Library, APPIUM For Windows, APK App Info On Google Play and Node.js. or we need to add/omit a software to this list.

Comment: I appreciate that you want to keep your question as simple as possible. At the same time, you need to include enough information so that we can provide an answer that is helpful for you The more specific details you give, the more specific an answer you will get.

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice, in my above comment I have mentioned softwares required as per my understanding for Appium automation. Feel free to comment on that.